# Using Integer.parseInt crashes my program

Tags: java

I have looked all over the internet and cannot find my out why this is happening to my program.
Basically I am trying to make a TextField that that makes a string of numbers, and that string is turned into an integer and the label is changed to the number +1 
Whenever I attempt to use Integer.parseInt It crashed

Here is my Code

```
public class dfadsfa {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField textField;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    dfadsfa window = new dfadsfa();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public dfadsfa() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */

    String Text;
    int Number = Integer.parseInt(Text); //This line Screws it up

    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblNumber = new JLabel("");
        lblNumber.setBounds(198, 181, 61, 16);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblNumber);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Text = textField.getText();
                lblNumber.setText(Number+1+"");
            }
        });

        textField.setBounds(163, 140, 130, 26);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);


    }

}
```

This is the message that shows up-

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
at dfadsfa.<init>(dfadsfa.java:42)
at dfadsfa$1.run(dfadsfa.java:21)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Sorry, but _"It crashed"_ is insufficient.  You must [edit] your post and include the complete stack trace, as well as identify the line in your program that throws the exception.  Just because in this case the error is obvious on inspection does not mean you should not include the required information.

Comment: How does it crash? What is the error message? How about sharing the stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text is not initialized , So it gives a NumberFormatException. 
Here Integer.parseInt() method will give the NumberFormatException if the passed string does not contain a parsable integer.

Use

`String Text = "0"` to solve the problem

Comment: This changed my changes my label to 0, my goal is to change it to a number I enter +1

Comment: Use `Text = textField.getText();
             int out = Integer.parseInt(Text)+1;
             lblNumber.setText(out+"");`

Answer (score 5):

You have an unintialized String text. This is guaranteed to fail when trying to parse an int.

```
String Text;
int Number = Integer.parseInt(Text);
```

You should initialize this `text` before trying to parse the int.

Comment: You removed your earlier comment, but just to clarify you need to initialize `text` to something that can actually be parsed into an integer, i.e. you should call `Text = textField.getText();` before you call `Number = Integer.parseInt(Text);`.